# Sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m×n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n×p$ matrix , then how do we show that $AB$ can be written as a sum of $n$ matrices each of order at most $1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to take an $$m * n$$ matrix where all the positions are numbered a1, a2... ai, multiply it with $$n * p$$ where all the positions have been numbered b1, b2... bj. Per matrix multiplication, you're going to notice that each position is increasing in a linear fashion and that it is impossible for it to increase by any other facter than an order of at most 1.

Basically, A1 x B1 = A1B1 = A1 + A1 ... b1 number of times.